# Dockerized Node API using official Node image

Tags: node.js, docker

The below code runs the `server.js` without installing the node modules in the `package.json`, so it run into an error `Error: Cannot find module 'koa'`. Is it possible to install node modules on the prebuilt Docker Node image (https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node) using docker-compose?

I tried `command: "yarn install && yarn start"` in `docker-compose.yml`, but that's not valid.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  my-api:
    image: node:16-alpine
    user: node
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
      - /home/node/app/node_modules
    command: "yarn start"
    expose:
      - 5000
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-api",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "install": "yarn install",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "koa": "^2.13.0",
    "@koa/cors": "^3.1.0",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.0",
    "koa-logger": "^3.2.1",
    "koa-router": "^9.0.0"
  }
}
```

`server.js`

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');
const logger = require('koa-logger');
const Router = require('koa-router');
const cors = require('@koa/cors');

console.log('server ready');
```

Comment: You can run a script that runs the install and start. In the compose you'll then have only one command.

Comment: May I know why you want to do it like that and not create your own Dockerfile using the base image as `node:16-alpine`?

Comment: @EAzevedo how to do that?

Comment: @Eranga Heshan prebuilt image is more streamlined inside docker compose compared to building a custom image based on node. I’ve used the custom image approach before and that works fine. I’m trying this because it’s “cleaner”.

Comment: This seems like a roundabout way to run Node on code that's outside the Docker ecosystem; if you don't want to build a custom image, you might find it easier and more straightforward to install Node on your host (or use the Node that's already installed with your OS).  Generally you should be running commands like `npm install` in your image's Dockerfile and not trying to get them to re-run when you run the container.